# How secure is inter-app communication in iOS?

Tags: iphone, security, url-scheme

I have come across a few articles on inter-app communication on iOS, e.g. "[2-way app integration on the iPhone: How it works](http://blog.innerfence.com/2009/01/05/2-way-app-integration-on-the-iphone-how-it-works/)", and "[Apple Approved iPhone Inter-process Communication](http://mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/)". Essentially they use custom URL schemes to communicate. My question is what are the security concerns if I were to pass some sensitive data, such as login credentials?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use URL schemes for any sensitive data. They are in no way designed to be secure.

Instead you should use the Keychain mechanisms in iOS which are designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Could you please tell me a scenario where using URL schemes may be insecure?

Comment: It is passed unencrypted between the processes. Additionally you have no control over the receiver, so any ill-willed process could register the same url-scheme and intercept the credentials

Comment: I knew that. But for a unjailbroken phone, isn't it only the intended app would get to see that?

Comment: If your intended app is not installed on the iPhone, but instead another app registers the same url-scheme, then you might inadvertently send the url to the wrong app. There are no built-in protections on these schemes and no way to check which app have registered a custom scheme.

Comment: Claus, [the iOS documentation for SecItemAdd](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000898) explains that you can use the kSecAttrAccessGroup attribute on keychain items to specify a keychain access group which can access that item. Isn't that equally insecure? Can't a rogue application simply declare the same keychain-access-groups entitlement and access the sensitive data?

Comment: "If more than one third-party app registers to handle the same URL scheme, there is currently no process for determining which app will be given that scheme": https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: I don't think it is insecure. The two apps involved simply need to collaborate. They can both add "Payamas" backwards prior to their actual schemes to create cryptation. Also it is kind of hard for a thief like developer to know which app communicate, how and with what - to feel like he will gain any value from it. He will need know both apps and have to be extremely precise with this target from his own app.